# Auto Refresh qpdfview

Tags: debian, xfce, documentation, configure, qpdfview

I am writing documents in latex that I compile to produce a pdf file opened with qpdfview (with the --unique option).

Once compiled after a modification on the tex .document, I would like qpdfview to automatically refresh the pdf.

I don't know how to configure qpdfview for this autorefresh feature.

Looking at the documentation there is the option

> [documentView] autoRefreshTimeout=1250

but I do not know how to handle this option.

```
      ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.        OS: Debian 9.8 stretch
    ,g$$P""       """Y$$.".      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
   ,$$P'              `$$$.      Uptime: 2h 40m
  ',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:    Packages: 1812
  `d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$     Shell: bash 4.4.12
   $$P      d$'     ,    $$P     Resolution: 1920x1080
   $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'     DE: XFCE
   $$\;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      WM: Xfwm4
   Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'          WM Theme: Moheli
   `$$b      "-.__               GTK Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2]
    `Y$$                         Icon Theme: Zafiro-icons
     `Y$$.                       Font: TeX Gyre Bonum 10
       `$$b.                     CPU: Intel Core i5-6440HQ CPU @ 3.5GHz
         `Y$$b.                  GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
            `"Y$b._              RAM: 3460MiB / 7599MiB
                `""""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To turn the option on, go to the **Edit** menu, select **Settings...** and then check the **Auto-refresh** checkbox in the **Behavior** tab.

To change the default timeout values, you would need to edit the configuration file - likely `~/.config/qpdfview/qpdfview.conf`. You should be able to modify/add parameters under the `documentView` section header:

```
[documentView]
autoRefresh=true
.
.
.
```